# increment for loop with inner while loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to increment an outer for loop before the inner while loop increments. Is there a way to do this? My code is below.
I want the code to go through all the i's before j increments. Thanks

```
data_files = glob.glob('4e3_2048_*.ksz_cl.txt')
for i in data_files:
    data_i = pd.read_csv(i, sep=" ", header = None)
    data_i.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']    
    cls = []
    j=0
    while j<=len(i):
        Z = [data_i['c'][j]]   
        #j=j+1
        cls.append(Z)
```

Comment: Why do you want to increment the outer loop first?

Comment: I need to make a list of the first item in the 'c' column for all the files 'i', before going to the next item in the 'c' column. Is there a better way to do this?@HenryWoody

Comment: just place an outer loop `for l in ['c', 'b', 'a']` then the innermost loop `Z = [data_i[l][j]]`?

Comment: Reverse it, make `j` the outer loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to increment the outer loop before the inner loop—incrementing the outer loop first would just move to a new version of the inner loop (basically starting over). I think you want to switch the order of your loops.

Here is an example:

```
data_files = glob.glob('4e3_2048_*.ksz_cl.txt')
dfs = []

for file in data_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=" ", header=None)
    df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    dfs.append(df)

cls = []

for i in range(len(dfs[0])):
    row = []
    for df in dfs:
        row.append(df['c'][i])
    cls.append(row)
```

The first loop is just to read all the files in. The logic from that first loop can just be incorporated into the inner-most loop (`for df in dfs`) which you may want to do if your files are very large and cannot all be stored in memory at once. It's useful to separate these loops so that you know how many rows you'll need to do.

Here is an example with just two loops:

```
data_files = glob.glob('4e3_2048_*.ksz_cl.txt')
first_file = pd.read_csv(data_files[0], sep=" ", header=None) #for the loop max val
cls = []

for i in range(len(first_file)):
    row = []
    for file in data_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=" ", header=None)
        df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        row.append(df['c'][i])
    cls.append(row)
```

You'll probably also want to add some error (`IndexError`) handling.